# connection close - antes ou depois?

Tags: php, mysql

O que é melhor, fechar antes ou depois do while?

Por exemplo,
**Modo1**:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM tabela";
$rs = mysql_query($sql,$connect);

mysql_close($connect);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
  $nome = $row['nome'];
  echo $nome;
}
```

ou **Modo2:**

```
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM tabela";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql,$connect);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
      $nome = $row['nome'];
      echo $nome;
    }

    mysql_close($connect);
```

- O close antes ou depois do while? Modo1 ou Modo2?

Comment: O melhor é não usar as [funções mysql_*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)